# Protect routes in laravel when manually entered address

Tags: php, laravel

I am studying and registering information in the database, out of curiosity I did the test to access the route of registration directly through the URL and I came across the following error "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.". How can you protect me from this mistake?

route for view:

```
Route::get('/cadastro', 'UserController@index');
```

route for action do form:

```
Route::post('/cadastrar', 'UserController@cadastrar');
```

form:

```
<form method="post" action="{{url('cadastrar')}}">
        @csrf
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Usuário">
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email">
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="senha">
        <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
    </form>
```

method register for controller:

```
public function cadastrar(Request $request){

        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name'=>'required',
            'password' =>'required'
        ]);
            $user = new User();
            $user->name = $request->input('name');
            $user->email = $request->input('email');
            $user->password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
            $user->save();  

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your form, change the `action` to `action="{{route('nameOfRoute')}}"`

And just name your route like usual. 
 You can also make a `Route::resource()`  to make things more clean and standard.

Comment: erro: Route [cadastrar] not defined. But it's

Comment: Did you name the route in the web.php file?

Comment: Route::post('/cadastrar', 'UserController@cadastrar');

Comment: You haven't named it. Do it like so: Route::post('/cadastrar', 'UserController@cadastrar')->name('nameOfRoute');